# Solving numerical problems using Newtons method

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I am studying numerical analysis and also solving algorithms which is described in book. My problem is  about Newton's method. In general, if some function is given and we have to find root, how can we determine  derivative of function in code? or even limit? because as you know Newton's method involves derivative and makes iteration like this. 
Suppose some function `f(x)` and initial guess,`p0,` then `p(n)=p(n-1)+f(p(n-1))/f'(p(n-1))` here `f'`  denotes derivative of `f`.

How can I approximate it in code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [implementing the derivative in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559695/implementing-the-derivative-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the function is given, you can do a couple of things

1. symbolic differentiation, if you have a symbolic representation of your function
2. Numerical differentiation, if you only have point-value pairs
3. Interpolate with a polynomial and differentiate that (symobolically of course)

All Options are viable. Which of these is most suited to your problem depends on the function and also the time you want to invest in coding and/or reading up on how to do it.

**Edit:** If you already know the function before execution time, then compute the differential by hand and implement it as a function. You should also already have implemented your `f(x)` as a function like this

```
float f (float x) {
    // ...
}
```

And thus:

```
float df_dx (float x) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: can i use this?   (f(x + h) - f(x - h))/2h

Comment: You could try. Whether this gives you a good approximation of your derivative depends on the smoothness of your function, how large you choose `h` and also whether you can evaluate your function at arbitrary points.

Comment: Also: have a look at the article linked as possible duplicate. It explains derivatives and their pitfalls pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Newton's Method, you will need to know the derivative of the function and code it in.

Otherwise, you can go with the [Secant Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) which doesn't require knowing the derivative. But it converges at a slower rate.

Comment: i know derivative,i want to implement it in c++,i have wrote secant method already

Comment: So if you already know what `f'(x)` you can't just implement it?

Comment: yes @Mysticial,just i wanted  approximate expression  such that,not loss any  data while calculation  derivative at given point

Comment: The algorithm that approximates `f'(x)` in Newton's Method (I think) ends up reducing to the Secant Method after some algebra.