# Implementation Of Differentiation & Integration(Calculus) In C++

Tags: algorithm

Is there any suitable Algorithm for Integration & Differentiation which I could implement by C++ or C. Just name it with reference. I would be very happy with your answer & explanation if you kind enough to provide a sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Numerical or symbolic integration/differentiation?

Comment: "Is there any suitable Algorithm for Integration & Differentiation which I could implement by C++ or C" - if there wasn't, applications like Matlab couldn't have been written. "Just name it with reference": `trapezoidal rule &` (or `const trapezoidal rule &`, if you want a read-only solution).

Comment: Numarical integration/differentiation @AndersForsgren

Comment: Thank You very much ......... You save a lot of time.... :) @H2CO3

Comment: This has the answer to half your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559695/implementing-the-derivative-in-c-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Calculus c++ library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/calculus-cpp/).

It is easy to use. You can declare variables as `Variable x="x",y="y";`, and functions as `Function f=sin(x)*sin(y);`.

And you can differentiate it for example with respect to x as 
`Function dfdx= f->get_partial_derivative(x);`