# Calculate derivative using limit definition in C

Tags: c, derivative

I should write a function that calculates the derivative of `sin^2(x)/x+3` by using the formula `(f(x+h)-f(x))/h`.

I have read many examples in Internet but they were complicated. I don`t know much about coding, I should calculate this derivative only by **making a function.**

For ex.

```
float deriv(float x,float h)
```

How can we write this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to do this is with one function that calculates the derivative based on that definition, as well as with one function that implements that specific formula.

```
float deriv (float x, float h) {

     float dydx = (function(x+h) - function(x))/h;
     return dydx;
}

float function(float x) {
    // Implement your sin function here evaluated for the argument
}
```

Keep in mind that the definition of a derivative works for as h->0 and to get f'(x) requires stuff to cancel. What we have here is a numerical estimate that is a glorified gradient equation. Good luck!

Comment: Selection of a good `h` is skipped here - it is not so trivial.  So the problem, in the general case, remains unanswered - yet this appears to meet OP's basic need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @mcfisty, you can have the derivative function taking a pointer to the function that will be manipulated, making the derivative function more general.

```
double deriv(double x, double (*func)(double))
{
    const double h = 0.0001;
    return (func(x+h) - func(x)) / h;
}
```

Note this is an approximation. Ideally we'd find the limit as h approaches 0, but that is impossible to do programmatically without having to know what the definition of `func` is—and we want to keep the definition of the derivative as general as possible.

Comment: Floating point math has a logarithmic distribution of values.  `x + h` is meaningless for large and small values of `x` - not a good step toward "keep the definition of the derivative as general as possible" .  `const double h = x*0.0001;` makes more sense, yet edge cases need consideration.

Comment: @chux what if I change it to 0.001? Is that better

Comment: As 0.001 or 0.01, consider `double f(double x) { return x; }` then `deriv(1e+20, f)`  incorrectly returns 0.0 instead of 1.0.  A good `h` depends on `x`.  See [Implementing the derivative in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1559695/2410359)